# Python I want to create 10 files in my directory

Tags: python, linux

I want to create ten `.txt` files in my directory `(myfile1.txt ... myfile10.txt)` if they don't exist

```
class test:
    def createfolder(self):
        import os
        if not os.path.exists("/home/administrator/Desktop/folder/"):
            os.makedirs("/home/administrator/Desktop/folder/")

        else: print("the folder already exist")

        for i in range(1,11):
            if not os.path.exists('/home/administrator/Desktop/folder/Fichier' + i + ".txt"):
                os.makedirs('/home/administrator/Desktop/folder/Fichier' + i + ".txt")




MonDoc=test()
MonDoc.createfolder()
```

> TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str

Comment: And what is the problem?

Comment: it's dosent works:TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str

Comment: `i` is a number, convert it to a string: `str(i)`

Comment: thank you it's works

Answer (score -1):

Use pathlib and format-strings:

```
from pathlib import Path
FOLDER = Path("/home/administrator/Desktop/folder/")

def createfolder():
    FOLDER.mkdir(exit_ok=True)
    for i in range(1,11):
        (FOLDER / f"Fichier{i}.txt").mkdir(exit_ok=True)

createfolder()
```

Answer (score -1):

You cannot concatenate a string and an interger.

Convert your `i` into a string using `str(i)`

```
class test:
    def createfolder(self):
        import os
        if not os.path.exists("/home/administrator/Desktop/folder/"):
            os.makedirs("/home/administrator/Desktop/folder/")

        else: print("the folder already exist")

        for i in range(1,11):
            if not os.path.exists('/home/administrator/Desktop/folder/Fichier' + str(i) + ".txt"):
                os.makedirs('/home/administrator/Desktop/folder/Fichier' + str(i) + ".txt")




MonDoc=test()
MonDoc.createfolder()
```